# Create a custom Transformer In Java spark ml

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, transformer-model

I want to create a custom Spark Transformer in Java.

The Transformer is text preprocessor which acts like a Tokenizer. It takes an input column and an output column as parameters.

I looked around and I found 2 Scala Traits HasInputCol and HasOutputCol.

How can I create a class that extends Transformer and implements HasInputCol and OutputCol?

My goal is have something like this.

```
   // Dataset that have a String column named "text"
   DataSet<Row> dataset;

   CustomTransformer customTransformer = new CustomTransformer();
   customTransformer.setInputCol("text");
   customTransformer.setOutputCol("result");

   // result that have 2 String columns named "text" and "result"
   DataSet<Row> result = customTransformer.transform(dataset);
```

Answer (score 3):

As [SergGr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182660/serggr) suggested, you can extend `UnaryTransformer`. However it is quite tricky.

NOTE: All the below comments apply to Spark version 2.2.0.

To address the issue described in [SPARK-12606](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12606), where they were getting `"...Param null__inputCol does not belong to..."`, you should implement `String uid()` like this:

```
@Override
public String uid() {
    return getUid();
}

private String getUid() {

    if (uid == null) {
        uid = Identifiable$.MODULE$.randomUID("mycustom");
    }
    return uid;
}
```

Apparently they were initializing uid in the constructor. But the thing is that UnaryTransformer's `inputCol` (and `outputCol`) is initialized before `uid` is initialized in the inheriting class. See `HasInputCol`:

```
final val inputCol: Param[String] = new Param[String](this, "inputCol", "input column name")
```

This is how `Param` is constructed:

```
def this(parent: Identifiable, name: String, doc: String) = this(parent.uid, name, doc)
```

Thus, when `parent.uid` is evaluated, the custom `uid()` implementation is called and at this point `uid` is still null. By implementing `uid()` with lazy evaluation you make sure `uid()` never returns null.

In your case though:

```
Param d7ac3108-799c-4aed-a093-c85d12833a4e__inputCol does not belong to fe3d99ba-e4eb-4e95-9412-f84188d936e3
```

it seems to be a bit different. Because `"d7ac3108-799c-4aed-a093-c85d12833a4e" != "fe3d99ba-e4eb-4e95-9412-f84188d936e3"`, it looks like your implementation of the `uid()` method returns a new value on each call. Perhaps in your case it was implemented it so:

```
@Override
public String uid() {
    return Identifiable$.MODULE$.randomUID("mycustom");
}
```

By the way, when extending `UnaryTransformer`, make sure the transform function is `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to inherit your `CustomTransformer` from [org.apache.spark.ml.UnaryTransformer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/UnaryTransformer.html). You may try something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.UnaryTransformer;
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable$;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import scala.Function1;
import scala.collection.JavaConversions$;
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyCustomTransformer extends UnaryTransformer<String, scala.collection.immutable.Seq<String>, MyCustomTransformer>
{
    private final String uid = Identifiable$.MODULE$.randomUID("mycustom");

    @Override
    public String uid()
    {
        return uid;
    }


    @Override
    public Function1<String, scala.collection.immutable.Seq<String>> createTransformFunc()
    {
        // can't use labmda syntax :(
        return new scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1<String, Seq<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public Seq<String> apply(String s)
            {
                // do the logic
                String[] split = s.toLowerCase().split("\\s");
                // convert to Scala type
                return JavaConversions$.MODULE$.iterableAsScalaIterable(Arrays.asList(split)).toList();
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void validateInputType(DataType inputType)
    {
        super.validateInputType(inputType);
        if (inputType != DataTypes.StringType)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input type must be string type but got " + inputType + ".");
    }

    @Override
    public DataType outputDataType()
    {
        return DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, true); // or false? depends on your data
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. i guess it is because of a bug. I get ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Param d7ac3108-799c-4aed-a093-c85d12833a4e__inputCol does not belong to fe3d99ba-e4eb-4e95-9412-f84188d936e3.```

Comment: @LonsomeHell, just to double-check, are you sure you configured it with a valid input column?

Comment: Yes I used setInput with a valid column name.

Comment: I think it is releated to this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12606

Comment: I like the trick of using AbstractFunction1 so you don't nee to implement ALL the methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I have a few examples of custom Java Spark transforms here: https://github.com/dafrenchyman/spark/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mrsharky/spark/ml/feature

Here's an example with just an input column, but you can easily add an output column following the same patterns. This doesn't implement the readers and writers though. You'll need to check the link above to see how to do that.

```
public class DropColumns extends Transformer implements Serializable, 
DefaultParamsWritable {

    private StringArrayParam _inputCols;
    private final String _uid;

    public DropColumns(String uid) {
        _uid = uid;
    }

    public DropColumns() {
        _uid = DropColumns.class.getName() + "_" + 
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    // Getters
    public String[] getInputCols() { return get(_inputCols).get(); }

   // Setters
   public DropColumns setInputCols(String[] columns) {
       _inputCols = inputCols();
       set(_inputCols, columns);
       return this;
   }

public DropColumns setInputCols(List<String> columns) {
    String[] columnsString = columns.toArray(new String[columns.size()]);
    return setInputCols(columnsString);
}

public DropColumns setInputCols(String column) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{column};
    return setInputCols(columns);
}

// Overrides
@Override
public Dataset<Row> transform(Dataset<?> data) {
    List<String> dropCol = new ArrayList<String>();
    Dataset<Row> newData = null;
    try {
        for (String currColumn : this.get(_inputCols).get() ) {
            dropCol.add(currColumn);
        }
        Seq<String> seqCol = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(dropCol.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();      
        newData = data.drop(seqCol);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newData;
}

@Override
public Transformer copy(ParamMap extra) {
    DropColumns copied = new DropColumns();
    copied.setInputCols(this.getInputCols());
    return copied;
}

@Override
public StructType transformSchema(StructType oldSchema) {
    StructField[] fields = oldSchema.fields();  
    List<StructField> newFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
    List<String> columnsToRemove = Arrays.asList( get(_inputCols).get() );
    for (StructField currField : fields) {
        String fieldName = currField.name();
        if (!columnsToRemove.contains(fieldName)) {
            newFields.add(currField);
        }
    }
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(newFields);
    return schema;
}

@Override
public String uid() {
    return _uid;
}

@Override
public MLWriter write() {
    return new DropColumnsWriter(this);
}

@Override
public void save(String path) throws IOException {
    write().saveImpl(path);
}

public static MLReader<DropColumns> read() {
    return new DropColumnsReader();
}

public StringArrayParam inputCols() {
    return new StringArrayParam(this, "inputCols", "Columns to be dropped");
}

public DropColumns load(String path) {
    return ( (DropColumnsReader) read()).load(path);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even later to the party, I have another update. I had a hard time finding information on extending Spark Transformers to Java, so I am posting my findings here.

I have also been working on custom transformers in Java. At the time of writing, it is a little easier to include save/load functionality. One can create writable parameters by implementing DefaultParamsWritable. Implementing DefaultParamsReadable, however, still results in an exception for me, but there is a simple work-around.

Here is the basic implementation of a column renamer:

```java
public class ColumnRenamer extends Transformer implements DefaultParamsWritable {
    /**
     * A custom Spark transformer that renames the inputCols to the outputCols.
     * 
     * We would also like to implement DefaultParamsReadable<ColumnRenamer>, but
     * there appears to be a bug in DefaultParamsReadable when used in Java, see:
     * https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17048
     **/
    private final String uid_;
    private StringArrayParam inputCols_;
    private StringArrayParam outputCols_;
    private HashMap<String, String> renameMap;

    public ColumnRenamer() {
        this(Identifiable.randomUID("ColumnRenamer"));
    }

    public ColumnRenamer(String uid) {
        this.uid_ = uid;
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public String uid() {
        return uid_;
    }

    @Override
    public Transformer copy(ParamMap extra) {
        return defaultCopy(extra);
    }

    /**
     * The below method is a work around, see:
     * https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17048
     **/
    public static MLReader<ColumnRenamer> read() {
        return new DefaultParamsReader<>();
    }

    public Dataset<Row> transform(Dataset<?> dataset) {
        Dataset<Row> transformedDataset = dataset.toDF();
        // Check schema.
        transformSchema(transformedDataset.schema(), true); // logging = true
        // Rename columns.
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: renameMap.entrySet()) {
            String inputColName = entry.getKey();
            String outputColName = entry.getValue();
            transformedDataset = transformedDataset
                .withColumnRenamed(inputColName, outputColName);
        }
        return transformedDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public StructType transformSchema(StructType schema) {

        // Validate the parameters here...
        
        String[] inputCols = getInputCols();
        String[] outputCols = getOutputCols();
        // Create rename mapping.
        renameMap = new HashMap<> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputCols.length; i++) {
            renameMap.put(inputCols[i], outputCols[i]);
        }
        // Rename columns.
        ArrayList<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (StructField field: schema.fields()) {
            String columnName = field.name();
            if (renameMap.containsKey(columnName)) {
                columnName = renameMap.get(columnName);
            }
            fields.add(new StructField(
                columnName, field.dataType(), field.nullable(), field.metadata()
            ));
        }
        // Return as StructType.
        return new StructType(fields.toArray(new StructField[0]));
    }

    private void init() {
        inputCols_ = new StringArrayParam(this, "inputCols", "input column names");
        outputCols_ = new StringArrayParam(this, "outputCols", "output column names");
    }

    public StringArrayParam inputCols() {
        return inputCols_;
    }
    public ColumnRenamer setInputCols(String[] value) {
        set(inputCols_, value);
        return this;
    }
    public String[] getInputCols() {
        return getOrDefault(inputCols_);
    }

    public StringArrayParam outputCols() {
        return outputCols_;
    }
    public ColumnRenamer setOutputCols(String[] value) {
        set(outputCols_, value);
        return this;
    }
    public String[] getOutputCols() {
        return getOrDefault(outputCols_);
    }
}
```